# Extracting numeric id value from selectize input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, selectize.js

I'm trying to use selectize input in a shiny app and am having difficulty in extracting the associated id variable. Users will select a name variable in the single_item dropdown, but I want to be able to extract the id associated with that name to use in another function.

The first part of the server code I have provided below gives me the correct dropdown values based on reactive objects elsewhere in the app, but I can't get work out how to get the id value into the correct format that it essentially represents one numeric value that can be inserted into the other function.

Any help much appreciated as I'm fairly new to shiny and much of the info on here seems to be .js which I don't know at all.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have pasted the id and name together in the dropdown selection, so now I just need to be able to select the first 4 numbers from the selected option - this seems like it might be easier to achieve??

```
# ui

selectizeInput('single_item', 'Select an item', choices = NULL, options = list(maxOptions = 10))

# server

# allow the single item to be selected
observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'single_item', 
    choices = paste0(reactive_data()$id, sep = " - ", reactive_data()$name),
    server = TRUE)
  })

# create a reactive object that selects id variable from the reactive data created earlier
single_proj <- reactive({
    req(input$single_item)
    
    data <- reactive_data()
    
    data <- data %>%
      select(id)

    data   
  })

# assign the single value to use in another function
id <- single_proj()$id
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.